# 401 Error While Accessing Youtube API From Angular Component

Tags: angular, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, angular8

I am working on an Angular app, where I get a list of Youtube Videos using the YouTube API. Below is the service I created to consume the API.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {from, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {first, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YoutubeService {

    apiKey = 'AIzaSy...';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getMessage(): string {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }

    getVideosForChannel(channel: string, maxResults: number): Observable<object> {
        const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=' + this.apiKey +
            '&channelId=' + channel + '&order=date&part=snippet &type=video,id&maxResults=' + maxResults;
        return this.http.get(url)
          .pipe(map((res) => {
            return res;
          }));
    }
}
```

To display the list of videos on the component, I'm using the following code

```
this.youtubeService.getVideosForChannel('UCl7379cd3Pv81tySqs0TR7A', 10)
      .subscribe(list => {
        for (let item of list['items']) {
          console.log(item);
          this.videos.push(item);
        }
      });
```

The problem is I'm having the following error message:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=A…=date&part=snippet%20&type=video,id&maxResults=10", ok: false, …}
```

Can someone help me with the error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the request **link** in the browser and check the output, and if you get any errors like a bad request, you need to make sure you have passed a valid key without extra whitespaces and doesn't exceed the maximum limit of requests per key in a day.

Comment: I've already tried that, when I put the requested link in the browser I didn't receive any error.

Comment: so you have received the expected output, true?

Comment: Yes, I received the expected output